# Adding table using jquery and mouse processing

Tags: jquery, row, addition, mouseover

I have one interesting question.

I want to add rows to table using jquery, and after to make added row to respond to mouseover event, but code does not work.

The problem is that row is added as expected, but does not respond to mouseover event.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Urmas.

Code is following:

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
  .elem {
    color: purple;
    background-color: #d8da3d 
    }
  </style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
</script>   



</head>

<body>
<table id="table">
   <thead>  
    <tr>
        <th>Numbers</th>
        <th>Letters</th>
        <th>Symbols</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class='elem'>111</td>
        <td class='elem'>aaa</td>
        <td class='elem'>@@@</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='elem'>222</td>
        <td class='elem'>bbb</td>
        <td class='elem'>###</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='elem'>888</td>
        <td class='elem'>iii</td>
        <td class='elem'>???</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>        
</table>

<input type = "button" id = "add" value = "add row" />


<script type="text/javascript">

$(".elem").mouseover(function() {

alert("over");
});

$("#add").click(function() {

$row_to_add="";

$row_to_add+="<tr>";
    $row_to_add+="<td class='elem'>999</td>";
    $row_to_add+="<td class='elem'>qqq</td>";
    $row_to_add+="<td class='elem'>&&&</td>";
$row_to_add+="</tr>";

 $("#table tr:last").after($row_to_add);

});


</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to add event listeners to elements that you add dynamically.  Eg:

```
$(document).on(".elem", "mouseover", function() {
    //...
}
```

> > Description: Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

(Per Mattias Buelens, who pointed out the **live** function is deprecated.)

Comment: Great! Thank You very much!  This were the problem.

Comment: Since jQuery 1.7, [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated in favour of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), which is now your all-in-one binding function. `$("#table").on("mouseover", ".elem", function() { ... });`

Comment: @MattiasBuelens but either one is acceptable, no?  It looks like **on** is a more general function that can handle more scenarios.

Comment: @dbaseman They both work, and most likely they'll keep working for a while. However, since `live` is deprecated, it may be removed from jQuery in some future release. It's very unlikely that they'll actually remove it, but for newly written code it's best to avoid using deprecated functions and instead use the latest and greatest functions.

Comment: @dbaseman `.on(...);` is a lot faster as it does not need to climb whole dom tree. And really new projects should use `.on` as `.live` will be removed some day soon and that could make it harder staying up to date if all code requires refactoring. Is that already just shortcut to `.on(...)`?

Comment: @MattiasBuelens thanks for clarifying, I didn't realize **on** was actually deprecated.  Updated my answer "for the record". :P

Comment: I am really sorry to tell you, but live works well, but on does not work, works only with static elements.

scriptcode with live

    $(".elem").live("mouseover", function(){
     alert("over");
    });

code with on

    $(".elem").on("mouseover", function(){
     alert("over");
    });

Comment: @UrmasRepinski `on` replaces *all* binding functions: `bind`, `delegate` and `live`. Your example uses `on` as a `bind` replacement. By passing a selector as second argument, as in [my example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868780/adding-table-using-jquery-and-mouse-processing/10868823#comment14161114_10868823), `on` acts as a `delegate` replacement. [It's all in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Heck, you can even find all equivalent calls on the documentation pages of the deprecated methods!

Comment: @UrmasRepinski one more update.  Sorry about that.  Mattias is correct, there's documentation on how to convert from *live* to *on* here. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: allright, where is the error? i had replaced live with on, and it started to works with static elements again. As it works with static, but not with dynamic, i assume that there is bug in on function. I am too lazy to do somebody else's work. Will use live while on will not be fixed.

Comment: @UrmasRepinski yeah, I don't think it matters either way ;) but for the purists, see my updated answer.

Comment: no i had downloaded latest 1.7.2 jquery version, used syntax that dbaseman posted, but on still does not function.